# Where in Angular request lifetime to refresh JWT token

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

I'm still an Angular newbie. I want to refresh an access token, but I'm not sure where to do it.

I know about `guards and` `interceptors`. Where is the best place to do it? Are there trade-offs I must take into consideration?

Many questions here show how to do it in either case, but don't discuss the "why". I think the refresh should occur in the guard, at the very beginning of the request cycle, so the router knows whether to "activate" . But, most examples show it in an interceptor (either by looking at the expiry time, or waiting for a **401** and then refreshing).

Any advice would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE
I know the "how", what I need to understand is the why. Where is the correct place to refresh?

The guard's job is to simply check if the user is logged in, and if not, to redirect to a login page.

If the refresh token has expired, then I believe the guard should return false for `canActivate(ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot)` because the user although authenticated, no longer has a current grant.

That is why I'm leaning to putting it in the guard. But most examples including the excellent one below, show the refresh in the interceptor. Surely by then it's very late in the request cycle? What am I missing here - is this a matter of style only, or is there more to the angular request cycle that I should take into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **HttpInterceptor**. Since every API call passes trough interceptor, you can check if the token is still valid, proceed with the API call

If the token expired, show toastr alert and prevent any further API call.

For more info on using interceptor, visit this [10 ways to use Interceptors](https://blog.angularindepth.com/top-10-ways-to-use-interceptors-in-angular-db450f8a62d6)  and [Angular 7 JWT Interceptor](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/16/angular-7-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial)

> Complete Code:

**http-interceptor.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { SessionService } from './session.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

declare var toastr;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router, private sessionService: SessionService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    var token = this.sessionService.getToken();
    if (token != null && this.sessionService.isTokenExpired()) {
      this.sessionService.logOut()
      toastr.warning("Session Timed Out! Please Login");
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
      return throwError("Session Timed Out")
    } else {

      const authRquest = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
      })
      return next.handle(authRquest)
        .pipe(
          tap(event => {
          }, error => {
          })
        )
    }

  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
 providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: HttpInterceptorService,
        multi: true
      }
   ]
```

**session-service.ts**

```
  getToken(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('userToken');
  }

  getTokenExpirationDate(token: string): Date {
    token = this.getToken()
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

    if (decoded.exp === undefined) return null;

    const date = new Date(0);
    date.setUTCSeconds(decoded.exp);
    return date;
  }

  isTokenExpired(token?: string): boolean {
    if (!token) token = this.getToken();
    if (!token) return true;

    const date = this.getTokenExpirationDate(token);
    if (date === undefined) return false;
    return !(date.valueOf() > new Date().valueOf());
  }

  logOut(loginType?: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedin');
    localStorage.removeItem('userRole');

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this very nice and very complete example! What I am wondering however, is whether it is better to do it in the interceptor, like you've shown, or in a guard. Although I'm new to angular, my gut tells me the guard is a better location because that is where you decide whether to activate a route. But most examples are like this one, and I'm not sure if this is a issue of style, or there is something missing in my understanding...

Comment: `Interceptor` is the place to do it. In `Guard` we actually evaluate whether the user (logged in user) has access to the route. And `Guard` is the place to check routing, it is not related to http calls and tokens are related to Http Calls which should be handled in `interceptors`

Comment: Ohhhh... now I understand. So the guard is only to check whether user is **allowed** to access that route - whether he is actually logged in or not is irrelevant at that stage. Thanks for clarifying! :)

Comment: To be honest, I checked [the repo](https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-7-jwt-authentication-example/blob/master/src/app/_guards/auth.guard.ts) for that link you posted and it confirmed my suspicions. I'm not sure the guard is the best place. It doesn't perform some sort of ACL operation - it checks whether the user is logged in, and if not, redirects to a login page. If the refresh token has expired, then the answer to `canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)` should be false. I believe the guard is the place to do this, but I'm a newbie so I may be wrong.

Comment: I want to leave the question open just for a little while longer to get more ideas. You're probablt correct though, but I want to see what trade-offs people mention.

Comment: Sure..  I shared whatever I know. May be I am not correct or partially correct, I have worked on few projects in two organization, and everywhere the `interceptor` approach is used

Comment: Your example is still great, whether the code goes into the guard or interceptor, I'm gonna use it! :-)

Comment: Thanks. This is copied from a live project :)